# Не работает JS внутри компонента ReactJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ecmascript-6, компоненты

Хотел реализовать открытие меню-компонента с помощью декларации функции JS в теле этого же компонента, не реагирует полностью.

Сам компонент меню с функцией JS

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import './Menu.css';

    export default class Menu extends Component {
      render () {
        function menu() {
            var popup = document.getElementsByClassName('menu');
            var button = document.getElementsByClassName('butt');

            popup.classList.toggle('menu_active');
            button.classList.toggle('butt_active');
        }
        return (
            <div>
            <button className="butt" onClick={menu}>Menu</button>
            <nav className="menu">
            <a href="#">first part</a>
            <a href="#">second part</a>
            </nav>
            </div>
        );
      }
}
```

его css файл

```
    .butt {
    width: 120px;
    height: 40px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color: orange;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px red;
    margin-top: 45%;
    margin-left: 130%;
}
.butt_active {
    margin-top: 18%;
}
.butt:focus {
    outline: none;
}
.menu {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 400px;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 15px;

}
.menu_active {
    display: flex;
}
.menu a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 900;
    margin-top: 10%;
}
```

Компонент - родитель

```
import React from 'react';
import All from './All/All';
import Quiz from './Quiz/Quiz';
import Menu from './Menu/Menu';

export default function App () {

  return (
      <All>
      <Menu />
      <Quiz name="дешёвка" val="!"/>
      </All>
  );
}
```

Помогите!!!

Comment: рендер функция не предназначена для написания обработчиков. а логику показа, скрытия попапа храните в состоянии

Comment: На react надо писать в стиле react, а не в стиле jquery или нативного js.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` возвращает список нод. У списка нет свойства `classList`. В общем, учить матчасть.
Не говоря уж о том, что на реакте так писать вообще не нужно.

Comment: зачем вы используете react, если не используете его методотогии? как упомянул выше @StepanKasyanenko, цитата, "на react надо писать в стиле react, а не в стиле jq, vanilla js"

Answer (score 0):

Если совсем примитивно, то так:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';


    export default class Menu extends Component {
        constructor(){
            super();
            this.state = {
                classVarButt: 'butt',
                classVarNav: 'menu'

            }
        }

        render () {
            return (
                <div>
                    <button className={this.state.classVarButt} onClick= {() => this.setState({classVarButt: 'menu_active', classVarNav: 'butt_active'})}>Menu</button>
                    <nav className={this.state.classVarNav}>
                        <a href="#">first part</a>
                        <a href="#">second part</a>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

**Прошу не забивать камнями, просили хоть как, но работало)**